# Magento 2.1.6 EE Admin Date Component not working

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-enterprise, uicomponent, magento2.1.6

I have a custom form, created via **Ui Component** form `holiday_form.xml` and after searching how to create a date component, it gives me a JS error that a can't get to work, if i change to input format, the field is rendered correctly with correct values.

Code from `holiday_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">holiday_form.holiday_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">holiday_form.holiday_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Holiday Information</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">holiday_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Block\Adminhtml\Holiday\Edit\BackButton</item>
        <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Block\Adminhtml\Holiday\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
        <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Block\Adminhtml\Holiday\Edit\ResetButton</item>
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Block\Adminhtml\Holiday\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Block\Adminhtml\Holiday\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="holiday_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Dufry\Entities\Model\Holiday\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">holiday_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="dufry_entities/holiday/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="holidays">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Holiday Name</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">holidays</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="date_from">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">holidays</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">date_from</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="date_to">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">holidays</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">date_to</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="description">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>                    
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Description</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">holidays</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>                
                <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="active">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">holidays</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">active</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

The error message is

```
Uncaught TypeError: utils.convertToMomentFormat is not a function
    at UiClass.prepareDateTimeFormats (date.js:175)
```

Any advices on what might be?

Comment: The problem now is ocurring on index of CMS pages, and i don't have nothing customized there. Anyone having this problem too?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone experiences this. Make sure that you have cleared your third-party caching too (in my case it was cloudflare.com)

Comment: I have cleared it.. no luck! .. using elastic cache aws

Comment: Or the browser's cache.